# How do i resize an object created in actionscript with the point of origin staying central

Tags: actionscript, resize

widthEssentially, i am creating objects in Flash using actionscript.  I currently have a problem where i am resizing the object in actionscript but as the point of reference seems to be the top left hand corner, the object when shrinking seems to also move towards the top left of the screen.

Is there a way to either code the point of origin for an object to the center of the object using code or to have it resize without seemingly moving?

my code for creating and resizing an object is like this (it will grow and shrink but at moment im just tryint to fix this problem before i move on):

```
var blob1:Loader = new Loader();
blob1.x = 1000;
blob1.y = 450;
blob1.load(new URLRequest("blob1.png"));
addChild(blob1);

blob1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, blobTween);
function blobTween(event:Event)
{
    var size = 0;
    if (size == 0){
            blob1.width += 5;
            blob1.height += 5;


    }else if (size == 1){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you update `x` and `y` while you change `width` and `height` ?

```
blob1.x += deltaWidth / 2
blob1.y += deltaHeight / 2
```

You increment width and height by 5, so `deltaWidth = 5` and `deltaHeight  = 5` .

NOTE: `deltaWidth / 2` doesn't divide equally, so you'll have slight shift. I suggest having `deltaWidth = 6` and `deltaHeight  = 6` , or something similar.

Comment: By deltaWidth and deltaHeight he means the w/h increment, in OP's code would be 5. I used to use this when I was a flash developer and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

GreenSock has a great library for doing just that; TransformManager.
http://www.greensock.com/transformmanageras3/

Answer (score 0):

my solution in the end was a bit strange.  I took the shape, divided it into 4 quarters and reattached them in flash by placing the objects in the same place and rotating them (as it rotates from the top left corner, the 4 quarters form a complete shape with each quarter having their top left corner in the centre of the "object").  I then resized them all at once to do it properly.

Whats weird is that the top right and bottom left corners required different math from the other two corners.  Which makes no sense whatsoever. 2 corners required width and height to be adjusted.  The other two corners required just width to be adjusted.  very strange but worked :/